# jQuery after onclick

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I've a form with different field, a validation summary and a button Sign up!
When I click on Sign up, if a field is empty, it active validation summary and until here there's no problem.

So the problem is that I would want active a jQuery script after it was clicked Sign up button and it appeared validation summary.

I try with

```
$(this).load(function()
```

but in effect it occur when the page is load and not after the button is clicked.
I try also use button's onclick ,but I have to use script after onclick and not while.

I used Validation group for all field of form, also button and for this reason it seems doesn't postback!

Answer (score 1):

Um your question is a bit unclear to me but wouldn't this work ?

```
$("#sign_btn").click(function(){
 alert("I was clicked");
});
```

sign_btn is the ID of the button.